# React Native useState function parameter confusion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, use-state

I am working on a React Native tutorial. In the code below, **courseGoals** was declared in the state using the useState function, but when calling the **setCourseGoals** function within the **addGoalHandler** function, *currentGoals* has been passed as the parameter and not *courseGoals*. Why is this? Is it because if we are using a function within **setCourseGoals**, the parameter will automatically always get the **courseGoals** value?

```
export default function App() {
  const [enteredGoal, setEnteredGoal] = useState('');
  const [courseGoals, setCourseGoals] = useState([]);

  const goalInputHandler = (enteredText) => {
    setEnteredGoal(enteredText);
  };

  const addGoalHandler = () => {
    setCourseGoals(currentGoals => [...currentGoals, enteredGoal]);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

And `[...currentGoals, enteredGoal]` in the code is appending the `courseGoals` array with new goal.

You can rename the parameter as you want. And it will still work. E.g:

```
setCourseGoals(courceGoals => [...courceGoals, enteredGoal]);
```